# Batch to open folder, resize and position it

Tags: batch-file

I want to open 2 folders, resize and position it SIDE by SIDE...

I already open it.

echo off
%system%\explorer.exe "[Path1]"
%system%\explorer.exe "[Path2]"

Comment: `cmd`/`batch` has no functionality to interact with GUI programs. You need another language for that.

Comment: Short answer you can't do this with a batch or cmd

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible, I'm afraid. Do you want to do a comparison? If so, you should use a proper tool like Beyond Compare or Araxis Merge.